# Metrics http_server_requests_seconds_count in spring boot application using cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs contains uri as "UNKNOWN"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, metrics, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

Metrics `http_server_requests_seconds_count` in Spring Boot application with version 2.0.8.Release exposed using spring actuator contains URI as:

> "UNKNOWN".

Spring Boot application is using `cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs` for exposing rest endpoints.
I have added `micrometer-registry-prometheus` dependency in my project.

```
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="POST",status="200",uri="UNKNOWN",} 2.0
```

I have tried adding micrometer-jersey2 dependency in my project.

Actual

```
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="POST",status="200",uri="UNKNOWN",} 2.0
```

Expected:

```
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/sayHello",} 2.0
```

Comment: Wasn't Apache CXF another/alternate JAX-RS implementation?`micrometer-jersey2` explicitely only supports the Jersey JAX-RS implementation.

Comment: Yes Apache CXF is an alternate implementation for JAX-RS. Micrometer provides only jersey module, there is no such module for CXF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the clarification in OP comments (CXF being another JAX-RS implementation): There's currently no support in Micrometer to handle CXF requests. It (Spring WebMvc) can't extract the optionally parameterized request url and in that case falls back to UNKNOWN. (Otherwise this could lead to a metrics explosion if your CXF endpoints provide some highly parameterizable URLs which get a lot of traffic.)

So you could have a look at the `micrometer-jersey2` implementation and derive a `micrometer-cxf` implementation ;) (Or if not already the case (use the search) - open up an issue with the Micrometer or CXF project. I am mentioning the latter, because they might be interessted in taking care of that implementation.)

Answer (score 1):

If you need cxf statistics for micrometer report, you can try

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.kdprog</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-micrometer-metrics</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The following statistics will be reported

```
cxf_requests_processed_total - total number of cxf requests ,
cxf_requests_seconds_sum     - total execution time of cxf requests,
cxf_requests_seconds_max     - maximum execution time of cxf request,
cxf_requests_success_total   - total number of successfully processed cxf requests,
cxf_requests_failed_total    - total number of failed cxf requests
```

for each web service method of every client or server cxf endpoint.

For spring applications add the following bean to your application configuration.

```
@Bean
public FactoryBeanListener cxfMicrometerBean(final MeterRegistry registry) {
    return new MicrometerFactoryBeanListener(registry);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.metrics.supported

You can make custom tag provider to override it:

```
@Bean
WebMvcTagsProvider webMvcTagsProvider() {
    return new DefaultWebMvcTagsProvider() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<Tag> getTags(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                     Object handler, Throwable exception) {
            return Tags.concat(
                    super.getTags(request, response, handler, exception),
                    Tags.of(Tag.of("uri",request.getRequestURI()))
            );
        }
    };
}
```

[More examples.](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=micrometer-metrics%2Fmicrometer%2Fmicrometer-master%2Fsamples%2Fmicrometer-samples-boot2%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fio%2Fmicrometer%2Fboot2%2Fsamples%2Fcomponents%2FHttpMetricsTagConfiguration.java)

Answer (score 0):

You can also collect cxf metrics for prometheus using io.github.ddk-prog:cxf-prometheus-metrics.

Add dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.ddk-prog</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-prometheus-metrics</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and the following bean to your application configuration.

```
@Bean
public FactoryBeanListener cxfPrometheusFeatureBean(final CollectorRegistry registry) {
    return new PrometheusFactoryBeanListener(registry);
}
```

You will get cxf_requests_total, cxf_requests_success, cxf_requests_failed, cxf_requests_seconds for each endpoint and operation in your spring boot actuator prometheus report.
For example,

```
cxf_requests_seconds{endpoint="server1",operation="server1Method",} 0.0157349
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebFlux on your project, you can make your custom tag provider by overriding:

```
@Bean
WebFluxTagsProvider webFluxTagsProvider() {
    return new DefaultWebFluxTagsProvider() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<Tag> httpRequestTags(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable exception) {
            return Tags.concat(super.httpRequestTags(exchange, exception), Tags.of(Tag.of("uri", exchange.getRequest().getPath().value())));
        }
    };
}
```

It works for me.